# Kinesis video streams CORS errors

Tags: amazon-kinesis

for less than 10% of our clients, the call to AWS.kinesisVideo api fails. It's blocked by the CORS policy.

Thing is, it's not happening for a vast majority of our clients. It's not related to a specific browser or version either. Sometimes it seems to be caused by the network since all devices in the network fails the same way, or sometime it'S caused by a specific device, other devices on the same network will work.

I'm very new to anything AWS.

Any idea or what I should look into to resolves this? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Kinesis Video Stream engineer here, first of all, I'm sorry for the trouble. We're aware of this intermittent CORS error. We have a fix planned.

Also just FYI, sometimes CORS errors can hide some other errors.

Comment: it is not intermittent for the clients affected.